# Perspective Image(equidistant parallel objects)

Tags: geometry

If I have four pillars in real world which are equidistant(the distance between any two consecutive pillars is equal), how can I verify that they are equidistant by using a 2D camera image(the image is taken from a corner such that the pillars are receding as we go towards the left corner of the image)? 
I came up with one solution

- Take the distance of corresponding points of pillars 1 and 2.
- Do the same for pillars 2 and 3.
- Now take the ratio of the above two distances.
- Now repeat this for pillars 2-3 and 3-4.
- The two ratios calculated above should be equal if the pillars are equidistant.

I searched online but couldn't find any solution. Can somebody verify if my solution is correct or if not, give some useful advice and point me in the right direction as to what I should be searching for?

Comment: I'm sorry. will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [cross ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio) is invariant under projective transformations. For four equidistant points 0,1,2,3 the cross ratio is

```
              (0-2)*(1-3)   (-2)*(-2)    4
CR(0,1;2,3) = ----------- = --------- = ---
              (0-3)*(1-2)   (-3)*(-1)    3
```

What you compute is the following:

1. (1-2)
2. (2-3)
3. (1-2)/(2-3)
4. (2-3)/(3-4)
5. (1-2)/(2-3) = (2-3)/(3-4)

This last term can be written as

```
(1-2)*(3-4)
----------- = 1
(2-3)*(2-3)
```

which is not exactly a cross ratio. One can show that the expression above is not projectively invariant.

So I suggest you stick with my expression above: put the locations of the pillars instead of the numbers 0,1,2,3 and if the final result is still 4/3 then the pillars are equidistant. (Of course you can never rule out the possibility that the original pillars might have been not equidistant but themselves some projectively deformed version of equidistance.)

Comment: Does the ratio always have to be 4/3 for equidistant points?

Comment: @user1777067: The cross ratio will always be 4/3 for originally equidistant points as long as you put them into the formula in the correct order. Different orders will result in different ratios.